# Uncaught TypeError using A-Frame 1.0.4 + A-Frame Extras nav-mesh and movement-controls

Tags: aframe

I'm getting the following error when using a simple plane as a nav-mesh and setting my rig's movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true".

```
aframe-extras.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at m.getClosestNode (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
    at o.getNode (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
    at i.<anonymous> (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
    at HTMLElement.tick (a-scene.js:709)
    at HTMLElement.render (a-scene.js:759)
    at bind.js:12
    at f (three.js:24703)
    at e (three.js:15038)
```

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>

<a-entity id="rig" position="0 0 0" movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true">
<a-entity id="camera" camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
</a-entity>

<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; height: 350; width: 350;" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" static-body nav-mesh>
</a-entity>
```

Is this a known bug? I first thought there was a conflict, but the problem persists even when all other includes are stripped out. All models load fine, and everything else is working.

Error happens only when movement is started by pressing arrow keys. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was that the nav mesh was too big. Using the same nav mesh scaled down worked. You might have to scale down your whole project, but that is the only solution I know of.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have another go at it shortly!