# Aframe, is aframe-extras navmesh still the way to go?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to make an Aframe scene using a landscape that the user can navigate, but I have had a lot of issues with the aframe-extras nav mesh. Even downloading the aframe-extras repo and installing, building the bundle and then trying to run http://localhost:8000/examples/castle I get the same error as in my scene.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.zones[t] is undefined
    getClosestNode bundle.js:8722
    getNode bundle.js:57166
    tick bundle.js:55425
    Aframe 57
```

I've looked into other posts like [Uncaught TypeError using A-Frame 1.0.4 + A-Frame Extras nav-mesh and movement-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550040/uncaught-typeerror-using-a-frame-1-0-4-a-frame-extras-nav-mesh-and-movement-co), but their error is different than mine.

Before I go on the journey to solve this issue, can anyone weigh in on whether I'd just be better off using a different program/approach to constrain my camera to a 3D surface that is a landscape model?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a landscape you are better of using physics-systems like Ammo.js
ref:
https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/AmmoDriver.md

[*Physics And Collisions (A-Frame Tutorial - WebVR)* on youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKYfYd3pk4I)

For your use case as for the landscape is concerned, you can try adding [ammo-body](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/AmmoDriver.md#ammo-body) property of kinematic to the third-person camera while the landscape and 3D models have property of static.
Try finding more about physics-system there are lot of tutorials and documentation available.